# Typescript 2.0 @Types/Express | Cannot find module

Tags: express, typescript-typings, tsc, typescript2.0

The Express type definitions for Typescript 2.0 result in unexpected errors when executing after running `npm install @types/express` and `tsc -t ES6` for ES6. The code compiles fine without the ES6 flag. Can anyone explain? I also have issues with other type definitions such as `ssh2`.

### Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
> mkdir humbug
> cd humbug
> touch blank.ts
> tsc blank.ts
> tsc -t ES6 .\blank.ts
```

Everything is fine so far.

```
> npm init .
...
> npm install @types/express
```

Things start going bad now

```
> tsc blank.ts
> tsc -t ES6 .\blank.ts
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts(16,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serve-static'.
node_modules/@types/serve-static/index.d.ts(16,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mime'.
```

Ok, well I better make sure that the types for serve-static and mime are installed.

```
> npm install @types/serve-static @types/mime
humbug@1.0.0 C:\Users\me\Desktop\humbug
`-- (empty)

npm WARN humbug@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN humbug@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Weird I got an ERR! code but the types were downloaded, Lets try compiling again

```
> tsc blank.ts
> tsc -t ES6 .\blank.ts
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts(16,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serve-static'.
node_modules/@types/serve-static/index.d.ts(16,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mime'.
```

Same error as last time.

### My Environment:

- Windows 10
- Node v6.6.0
- TSC 2.0.3

### Other definitions with the same problem:

```
node_modules/@types/cors/index.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
node_modules/@types/multer/index.d.ts(6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
node_modules/@types/ssh2/index.d.ts(26,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ssh2-streams'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning all this stuff (being .NET programmer), but I had similar issue this afternoon and this configuration seem to be working:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "node_modules/@types",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think only the typeRoots is useful, in my case I needed to go up one level "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]